# Javascript: How can I determine which characters in a string of text are capital letters?

Tags: javascript, fonts

**A note about the possible duplicate question**

The accepted answer to that question does not work.

It incorrectly reports spaces and other non-letter characters as toUpperCase==true. :-(

But I now see that one of the other answers does provide a successful solution.  The correct answer on this previous question is from ciembor. I'll leave this question posted because this accepted answer from Barmar correctly solves the issue.

**How can I determine which characters in a string of text are capital letters?**

My first try was testing with `.toUpperCase`, but non-letter characters also return true:

```
var text="Romeo & Juliet";

var characters=text.split('');

// and test with 

characters[i]===characters[i].toUpperCase()   // but spaces and "&" also test as true
```

Next I though of using regex and testing with `A-Z` but non-English character sets might have capital letters outside this range.

Anyone have way to determine if a character is a capital letter?

Comment: Well, there's [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294/283366) however I don't think JavaScript (ES5) supports unicode expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes

Comment: FYI, you don't need to split a string to access each character. Strings support array-like access

Comment: @Se0ng11. Thanks for the reference to that question.  The accepted answer to that question fails to correctly test for spaces, ampersands, etc.  But I now see that one of the other answers does provide a successful solution.  I'll leave this question posted as the accepted answer from Barmar correctly solves the issue.  Again...thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function isUpperCase(c) {
    return c == c.toUpperCase() && c != c.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Of course--eliminate false positives with !=c.toLowerCase.  Thanks...This is what I needed.