# How do I check if a Java String contains at least one capital letter, lowercase letter, and number?

Tags: java, string

I know that I could do this with a series of for loops that iterate through the string but that would be terrible programming. Well, my professor prefers I don't do it this way. I'd like to use regular expressions to do this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For a simple string check, a single sweep through the string is enough. Since Regex will not offer any significant benefit, here is a simple for loop to achieve the same :

```
private static boolean checkString(String str) {
    char ch;
    boolean capitalFlag = false;
    boolean lowerCaseFlag = false;
    boolean numberFlag = false;
    for(int i=0;i < str.length();i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if( Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            numberFlag = true;
        }
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            capitalFlag = true;
        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            lowerCaseFlag = true;
        }
        if(numberFlag && capitalFlag && lowerCaseFlag)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Test run:**

```
System.out.println(checkString("aBCd1")); // output is true
System.out.println(checkString("abcd")); //output is false
```

I think this should help OP's particular problem.

Comment: so if i do this: `System.out.println(checkString("A"));` and i do this `System.out.println(checkString("a"));` i recieve the same output -> `false`

Answer (score 21):

Example of @goshDeveloper's answer.

First create a Pattern variable with regular expression you want.

```
public final Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d).+$");
```

Second you can use it like this:

```
public boolean isTextValid(String textToCheck) {
return textPattern.matcher(textToCheck).matches();
}
```

Comment: And what pattern could this be for French and/or Spanish or ... ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294/731548

Answer (score 17):

Using Java 9:

```
public boolean isValid(String value) {
    return containsLowerCase(value) && 
           containsUpperCase(value) && 
           containsNumber(value);
}

private boolean containsLowerCase(String value) {
    return contains(value, i -> Character.isLetter(i) && Character.isLowerCase(i));
}

private boolean containsUpperCase(String value) {
    return contains(value, i -> Character.isLetter(i) && Character.isUpperCase(i));
}

private boolean containsNumber(String value) {
    return contains(value, Character::isDigit);
}

private boolean contains(String value, IntPredicate predicate) {
    return value.chars().anyMatch(predicate);
}
```

Comment: I like the readability of your solution. Performance-wise I dislike that every new condition requires an additional iteration over the value. Not a big issue on small / medium strings of course, but something to consider.

Comment: Solution requires min api 24

Answer (score 15):

Try regular expression

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$

descriptions are as follow
(?=.*[a-z])  -- check lower case letter
(?=.*[A-Z]) -- check upper case letter
(?=.*\d) -- check one digit exists
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks very promising. However, I have no experience with regex. Let's say I'd like to know if String _text_ contains at least one lower case letter, one upper case, and a number. How would I write that in the form of an 'if' statement?

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Are'nt these valid letters in french and spanish? aAàÀâÂæÆbBcCçÇdDeEéÉèÈêÊëËfFgGhHiIîÎïÏjJkKlLmMnNñÑoOôÔœŒpPqQrRsStTuUùÙûÛüÜvVwWxXyYÿŸzZáÁíÍóÓúÚ And what pattern could this be for French and/or Spanish or ... ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294/731548

Answer (score 11):

you can use :

```
public static boolean isTextContainUpperCase(String text) {
       if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
              return false;
       }
       return !text.equals(text.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Dude, this is the wrong answer if the text parameter characters already lower cased, it will also return true, for example `isTextContainUpperCase("a text");` will return true although it does not contains upper case character at all

Comment: Edit the if statement to !text.equals(text.toLowerCase()) and it will probably do what you ask (I edited the code in the answer)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to check whether your string contains uppercase letter or not, you can use below pattern:

```
String s="abcDe_shdgwU";    //you can have any String here

if(s.matches(".*[A-Z].*"))
   System.out.println("The String contains Uppercase letter(s)");
else
  System.out.println("does not contain Uppercase letter(s)");
```

Hope that helps.
Thank you.
Regards,
Tanumay Saha

Comment: Does it work with national character? E.g. Polish `ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ` ? They are all upper case but not part of ASCII `[A-Z]`

Comment: For lower case you can use ".*[a-z].*"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Character class of java. So for lowercase, `Character.isLowerCase(ch)`
`Character.isUpperCase(ch)`. For this *you have to iterate over the string*. I know that bit is irrelevant to you, however you can use `"\\d+"` for numbers in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String toCheck = "hasUppercasechar";
final boolean checkOk = !toCheck.chars().filter(Character::isUpperCase).findAny().isEmpty()
```

take a look at [java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and combine the checks you need

Answer (score 0):

```
See the code below;
public class passwordValidationOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pass = "Password1";
        System.out.println(valPassword(pass));
    }
    public static boolean valPassword(String password){
        if (password.length()>7){
            if (checkPass(password)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Too Small");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkPass(String password){
        boolean hasNum =false; //check if password has a number
        boolean hasCap =false; //check if password has uppercase character
        boolean hasLow =false; //check if password has lowercase characters
        char c; // used to check every single character in the password

        //loop for every single character in a string
        for (int i =0; i<password.length(); i++ ){
            //assign c to the character we are looking for
            c = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                hasNum = true;
            } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                hasCap = true;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                hasLow = true;
            }
            // check if all the three boolean variables are true
            if (hasNum && hasCap && hasLow){
                return true;
            }
        }
       return  false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
return password.length() >= 6
                && password.matches(".*\\d.*")
                && password.matches(".*[a-z].*")
                && password.matches(".*[A-Z].*");
```