# How can I test if a string contains any uppercase letter using Java with regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I want to use only regular expression

```
Raida => true
raida => false
raiDa => true
```

I have tried this :

```
   String string = "Raida"
   boolean bool = string.contains("?=.*[A-Z]");

   System.out.println(bool);
```

but it is not working

Comment: I want a solution by using **regular expression** on that question there were no example of using **regx** .

Comment: Donot read only the right answer. There might be other applicable answers at least for our scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40336434/1704453

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution would be:

```
boolean hasUpperCase = !string.equals(string.toLowerCase());
```

You convert the String to lowercase, if it is equal to the original string then it does not contain any uppercase letter.

In your example `Raida` you'll be compairing

`Raida` to `raida` these two are not equal so meaning the original string contains an uppercase letter

Answer (score 4):

The answer with regular expression solution has already been posted as well as many other rather convenient options. What I would also suggest here is using Java 8 API for that purpose. It might not be the best option in terms of performance, but it simplifies code a lot. The solution can be written within one line:

```
string.chars().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase);
```

The benefit of this solution is readability. The intention is clear. Even if you want to inverse it.

Answer (score 3):

Something which is close to your original idea. You basically just check whether there is a part in the string which contains an upper case letter - there can be any other characters after and before it. Here I included a small main method for testing purposes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("raid");
    test("raId");
    test("Raida");
    test("R");
    test("r");
    test(".");
    test("");
}

public static void test(String word) {
    //(?s) enables the DOTALL mode
    System.out.println(word + " -> " + word.matches("(?s).*[A-Z].*"));
}
```

I edited the example to deal with line breaks too. I just tested in on a Windows machine. This now uses DOTALL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL. In this mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator.

Comment: This is the only good answer, because it uses the String API.

Comment: @Asew `.*[A-Z].*` will fail if a *string* contains a line break. Or if a string is too large and the only uppercase letter is close at the start.

Comment: @Wiktor: Thanks for pointing this out. I totally forgot about line breaks to be honest. I updated my answer a bit (although I just tested it briefly on Windows). However, this does not solve the potential problem with very large strings.

Comment: @MDDCoder25 Ok, let's fix it like `"(?s)[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*"` - this is the best you can have with `.matches()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all non UpperLetter and calculate the length, if it is great or equal to 1 this mean there are at least one upper letter :

```
String input = "raiDa";
boolean check = input.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").length() >= 1;
```

---

Beside `String::contain` not use regex read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)

---

#### Ideone demo

Comment: Why would you write such complicated code when there is a method in the String API that let you do what you want?

Comment: There is nothing complicated about this code.

Comment: In which side you see it is complicated @Asew? and why this down-vote? can you please share your solution so we can learn from you something new?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern just needs to be surrounded by `()`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            bool = true;
        }
```

If you want an alternative to `regex`, try using `Character.isUpperCase()`.

```
boolean bool = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                bool = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bool);
```

Comment: Why not use the `matches(String regex)` in the String API ? The method was made for that and it spares you the time of literally re-writing the method...