# How to check if string contains both uppercase and lowercase characters

Tags: string, flutter, validation, dart

I need to validate password entered by user and check if the password contains at least one uppercase and one lowercase char in Dart.

I wrote this String extension:

```dart
extension StringValidators on String {
  bool containsUppercase() {
    // What code should be here?
  }

  bool containsLowercase() {
    // What code should be here?
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```dart
final text = passwordTextController.text;
final isValid = text.containsUppercase() && text.containsLowercase();
```

Is there any regexp for this purpose? Or it should be plain algorithm? Please help me to find out the elegant way. Thanks!

Comment: Traverse the string character by character from start to end.
Check the ASCII value of each character for the following conditions: 
If the ASCII value lies in the range of [65, 90], then it is an uppercase letter.
If the ASCII value lies in the range of [97, 122], then it is a lowercase letter.

Comment: See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336374/how-do-i-check-if-a-java-string-contains-at-least-one-capital-letter-lowercase. It is for Java. Hope you can find an analogy in Flutter

Comment: @Misa could you add an answer with Dart code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Dart programming language. I know Java. Anyway I guess the implementation behind ```Character.isUpperCase(ch)``` is the ASCII value as I mention in the first comment.

Comment: See also this code https://www.codevscolor.com/dart-check-character-uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only minimum 1 upper and minimum 1 Lower only, you could use this RegEx:

```
RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w+");
String a = "aBc";
String b = "abc";
String c = "ABC";
print("a => " + regEx.hasMatch(a).toString());
print("b => " + regEx.hasMatch(b).toString());
print("c => " + regEx.hasMatch(c).toString());
```

Expected Result:

```
I/flutter (10220): a => true
I/flutter (10220): b => false
I/flutter (10220): c => false
```

Reusable

```
extension StringValidators on String {

  meetsPasswordRequirements() {
    RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w+");
    return regEx.hasMatch(this);
  }

}
```

Use

```
final isValid = text.meetsPasswordRequirements();
```

Comment: don't need the \w+ there.  Once you've found the two letters, you're done.

Answer (score 12):

- Minimum 1 Upper case,
- Minimum 1 lowercase,
- Minimum 1 Numeric Number,
- Minimum 1 Special Character,
- Common Allow Character ( ! @ # $ & * ~ )

```
bool validateStructure(String value){
        String  pattern = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
        return regExp.hasMatch(value);
  }
```

Comment: It works great but I don't need to validate all of this conditions, only lowercase and uppercase characters. Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

```dart
extension StringValidators on String {
  bool get containsUppercase => contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'));
  bool get containsLowercase => contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  solve("coDE");
}

String solve(String s) {
  // your code here
  List _a = s.split("");
  String _b = "";
  List _x = [];
  List _y = [];
  for(var i in _a){
    if(i.toString() == i.toString().toUpperCase()){
      _x.add(i);
    }else{
      _y.add(i);
    }
  }
  
  if(_x.length == _y.length){
    _b = _a.join().toLowerCase();
  }else if(_x.length > _y.length){
     _b = _a.join().toUpperCase();
  }else if(_x.length < _y.length){
     _b = _a.join().toLowerCase();
  }
  return "$_b";
}

OR 

String solve2(String str) {
  return RegExp(r'[A-Z]').allMatches(str).length >
          RegExp(r'[a-z]').allMatches(str).length
      ? str.toUpperCase()
      : str.toLowerCase();
}
```