# How to query for emphasized words in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm trying to look for emphasized words in a text using the following regex

```
r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b'
```

My query on Mongodb is as follows:

```
db.getCollection('_collection').find({'text': {'$regex': "\b[A-Z]\b"}})
```

But I'm getting no results while I know there are documents that contain emphasized words in the text.

Emphasized word: "he really LOVES this towel" in this example the "LOVES" is an emphasized word.

Comment: That is not what the metacharacter `\b` is used for.

Comment: @S.M.Styvane I'm more baffled at what an :"emphasized word" is. We can kind of guess it meant "bold" ( hence the "b" ), but the OP seems off on their own little trip and isn't really listening. Best just to mark as "unclear what you are asking" anyway.

Comment: BTW, did you try `"\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b"`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular expression for checking if capital letters are found consecutively in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050381/regular-expression-for-checking-if-capital-letters-are-found-consecutively-in-a). Can someone else close please. I already voted as unclear but the OP confirms they are looking for "Capital" letters

Comment: @NeilLunn I didn't ask how to find this template using regex, the question is about finding it in Mongodb. In the question I write the template for finding this kind of words.

Comment: You actually have not said a single true of sensical thing here at all. I'd rather just see the question deleted altogether.

Comment: AFAIK, and @WiktorStribiżew commented; using `"\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b"` instead of `"\b[A-Z]\b"` in your find expression will do all you want  ;).

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('_collection').find({'text':{'$regex':'\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b'}})` ;).

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the regex format in Mongodb is a bit different than the one in Python.

The query I needed is:

```
db.getCollection('_collection').find({'text': {'$regex': '[A-Z]{2,}'}})
```

Which looks for emphasized words that contain at least two characters.

The query just for emphasized words without any additional conditions is:

```
db.getCollection('_collection').find({'text': {'$regex': '[A-Z]'}})
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Both python and MongoDB use the same `pcre` library! What is an "emphasized word" anyway?

Comment: @NeilLunn If you have the sentence - "he really LOVES this product", in this case "LOVES" is an emphasized word.