# RegExp match any capital letter from any alphabet

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, uppercase

All the answers I found concentrate either only on the latin alphabet `[A-Z]` or use `\p{L}` to match any letter from any alphabet. But how can I match any capital letter from any alphabet (in PHP)? E.g.: ÄÖÜÙ

Comment: Use `\p{Lu}`. Also, [tchrist has already answered it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294/3832970). And there is [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726645/3832970).

Comment: But I don't think, that my question is a duplicate, because unlike to the other questions I'm explicitly asking for capital letters *in any alphabet*. I would keep the question for other people to find the answer to this, I find simple question, much easier.

Comment: Well, *How to match uppercase word character with regex in PHP* is quite clear and straight-forward, I believe.

Comment: But the best answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052294/1768033) to the question with a very good explanation is found in *Regular expression for checking if capital letters are found consecutively in a string?*, which is not really focused on the same thing as this question or the question you mentioned.

Comment: You are  free to express the opinion on meta, if you do not agree. Besides, if others  agree with you, your question will be reopened. Anyway, I upvoted your question as it might do a good job for googlers.